# Выполнять, пока не получится

Tags: bash, linux

Я пытаюсь выполнить команду, которая все время возвращает ошибку (например, начинаю копировать файл, а в процессе запись обрывается или начинаю пинговать сервер, а он не отвечает). Как зациклить этот процесс, так чтобы команда выполнялась, пока не завершиться успехом (типа "автодозвон")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего выполнять команду в цикле и пока результат команды не будет без ошибки

```
#!/bin/bashuntil cp from to; do    echo Ошибка, повтор через секунду    sleep 1done
```

Здесь from и to - несуществующие файлы или файлы, к которым нет доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Гораздо проще просто игнорировать сигнал потери связи:

```
nohup cp ./from ./to
```